# Write once semantics for REST interface

Tags: rest

We have a REST interface that allows clients to create a Product resource. The Product can be associated with different kind of metadata.

/Product/{id}/metadata/{md_type}

The team wants a particular type of metadata to be written only ONCE. Subsequent updates should be rejected.

Currently,  a PUT request is used to create the metadata. The metadata is not assigned an ID. It is immutable. The PUT request is rejected if the metadata already exist.

Using PUT feels like a violation of REST semantics. What is the most RESTful way to handle the situation?

Comment: PUT sounds like the right one to me. In a way, this action still is idempotent, in the sense that the state of the system won't change if you call this endpoint multiple times, even though the HTTP response does change (same for DELETE which _is_ idempotent, while first call usually returns 2xx while second one returns 4xx). You could return 409 CONFLICT on subsequent calls for example. The main difference here is that the state won't change even for distinct values. What makes you think using PUT _violates REST semantics_?

Comment: @sp00m Everything I read about PUT says that PUT replaces existing data. Rejecting updates on subsequent PUTs violates the principal of least surprise for RESTful interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using PUT feels like a violation of REST semantics. What is the most RESTful way to handle the situation?

Using [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) is perfect here.

The simplest answer is that you are missing the fact that this is a [Conditional Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232); if the client were to send its request with an [If-None-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.2) header, then all of the generic handling of conditional requests would "just work", with the server returning a [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) if the resource already has a representation.

If the client doesn't include the If-None-Match header, then I don't think 412 is appropriate.  Perhaps [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5), or [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8); [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) is on point but may confuse humans who think that must refer to a credentials problem.

> Rejecting updates on subsequent PUTs violates the principal of least surprise for RESTful interfaces.

No, it doesn't.  Because `PUT` defines and constrains the semantics of the *request*, it doesn't obligate the server to fulfill the request.